# Assert Add to cart is diplayed for each product

Tags: webdriver

I want to check after I search for any product, there is whole list of products dispayed on page. I want to check Add to Cart button is displayed for each product. How do I check it??

Answer (score 1):

Find the common denominator to find the elements for the product by (preferably including the Add to Cart button) and then iterate over the Array/List/Enumerable and verify that it contains the Add to Cart button.